# Media searching ignored

Tags: search, media

Our site uses WordPress and there are so many media files.

Our site's medias' names are formatted with form like `[Car brand's name]-[number].jpg`, such as `Tesla-1.jpg` or `Aston Martin-3.jpg`.

So we could easily find the specific media for the article by searching with its name. but suddenly we couldn't search for a media.

We're trying to search for a media with its name, but search results don't change.

[image: media screen when doesn't search for anything]
(media screen when doesn't search for anything)

[image: media screen when searched for Aston Martin]
(media screen when searched for Aston Martin)

Of course, after filling the search textBox it showed me a loading icon, but results are always same. Why does this happen?

UPDATE+

I found that searching through grid view and list view gives me a different result.

(what I said "grid view" means media files displayed as grid out of thumbnail images, and "list view" means media files displayed as list out of thumbnail image, name, property and other detail things on WordPress admin page's media page.)

[image: searching with list view corrects]

searching with list view gives me a correct result, but with grid view always fail.

When using media with writing article, the media window always showed as grid view so searching results are always same.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress doesn't search images by their file names. It performs a search based on Title.

By default titles are generated automatically from file names, but it can be changed in editor by users.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, but we found that this is not an actual problem. please check that I implemented.